# React Redux onClick Call to Action Creator Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui

I have an onClick call in a Button.  I'm calling a method (handleQuery) to dispatch an action to my reducer.  Here's relevant code for the button and the handleQuery call.  I've tried various ways to make that onClick call on the button, but i can't see any sort of dispatch in Redux.

```
import { fetchData } from "../reducers/baseballReducer";

 const handleQuery = query => {
    fetchData(query);
  };

<Tab.Pane>
          <Button onClick={() => handleQuery("t205")} value="t205">
            T205
          </Button>
</Tab.Pane>

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchData
};
```

here's my reducer:

```
export const fetchData = query => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const queryBaseball = await baseballService.getByQuery(query);
    dispatch({
      type: "QUERY_DATA",
      data: queryBaseball
    });
  };
};



    const baseballReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INIT_BLOGS":
      console.log("Data", action.data);
      return action.data;
    case "UPDATE_DATA":
      return action.data;
    case "QUERY_DATA":
      return action.data;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and then finally here is my axios call to the backend

```
const getByQuery = query => {
  const request = axios.get(baseUrl + `?keyword=${query}`);
  console.log("Request", request);
  return request.then(response => response.data);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mapDispatchToProps, so your function fetchData can get the **"DISPATCH"** , but to get it you must call it by prop and not directly fetchData()

```
 const handleQuery = query => {
    this.props.fetchData(query);
 };
```

Comment: yes sir, that's the ticket...still confused on mapDispatch----thank you!

Comment: Feel free to ask anything on this comment thread or on my chat ;)